# How return Promise all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have 4 phases in this script that i'm working on, lets call phase one, phase two phase three and phase four. In each phase, i provide an array of files, i use the map function to iterate over each file, make some stuff and return what i need, like this:

phaseOne:

```
files = files.map((file) => {

  // do some stuff, and return.

});
```

And i'm using a reduce to call each phase:

```
[
 'phaseOne',
 'phaseTwo',
 'phaseThree',
 'phaseFour'
].reduce...

   call one, after call two, after call three.
```

The problem begins when i have a async operation inside phase two:

phaseOne:

```
files = files.map((file) => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {

     //async, if ok resolve.

   });    
});
```

So, when the phase three is called, i need to use Promise.all to wait for each item in the array:

phaseThree:

```
Promise.all(files).then((files) => {

   files = files.map((file) => {

     // sync operation.

   });

   return files; // is this right?
});
```

Now the real problem: how can i access the files in phase four? The files are just a `Promise { <pending> }`, and is empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Fatima, would you, please copy more lines of your code. It's really hard to understand what are try to achive.

Comment: Do you want to associate the files and the corresponding content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused based on what you're trying to do here. One thing I'd like to clarify is that `Promise.all()` is great for running dependencies in parallel. To run a single promise within `Promise.all()` completely defeats its purpose.

If I understand you correctly, you should instead look to do something like this (in pseudocode):

```
Promise.all([phaseOnePromise, phaseTwoPromise])
    .then(function(results) {
        // Results are returned in the order that they're passed into Promise.all()
        var phaseOneResults = results[0];
        var phaseTwoResults = results[1];
        return phaseThreePromise(phaseOneResults, phaseTwoResults);
    })
    .then(function(finalResult) {
        // You're done!
    });
```

You can also design phaseThreePromise to accept a single array parameter, and simplify it like this:

```
Promise.all([phaseOnePromise, phaseTwoPromise])
    .then(phaseThreePromise)
    .then(function(finalResult) {
        // You're done!
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Different names are not vital, but can help clarity. Your real problem is that you are not using the final data

```
Promise.all(files).then((files1) => {

   return files1.map((file) => {

     // sync operation.

   });

})
.then(files2 => {
    // use the data
});
```

Comment: depends on what the callback in .map returns - if that returns undefined for example, you'll end up with files2 being an array of undefined

Comment: What if i need use in other file? Can i just use files.then() ??

Comment: `files` is an array, not a Promise, so no, you can't use `files.then` as files will have no then method